# assistance in writing a bash function

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

i want the function "printReps" to print "error" 1 time for every number
that it receives more than once, however it is only printing an empty line.
here is the code
can anyone tell me where is my fault, thanks.

```
 function printReps {
echo $* | { read -a idNumbs
i=0
while (( $i < ${#idNums[*]} )); do
    error=0
    if (( ${idNums[i]} < 1 )); then
        let i++
        continue
    fi
    j=i+1
    while (( $j < ${#idNums[*]} )); do
        if (( idNums[i] == idNums[j] )); then
            idNums[j]=0
            error=1
        fi
        let j++
    done
    if (( $error == 1 )); then
        echo error
    fi
    let i++
done
}  
}
echo `printReps 1 1 23 4 78 23 1 4 9`
```

all the legal numbers are bigger than 0.

Comment: It would work if you use the same array you read your data into. `idNumbs != idNums`

Comment: thanks, stupid me!! 
another thing, shouldn't i use ${idNums[$i]} since "i" is a variable ?

Comment: the stuff in square brackets is evaluated as an arithmetic expression, so technically you do not need the dollar sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, that's a convoluted solution

```
printReps () {
    local seen
    for arg; do
        if [[ ${seen[$arg]} ]]; then
            echo error $arg
        fi
        seen[$arg]=yes
    done
}

printReps 1 1 23 4 78 23 1 4 9
```

```
error 1
error 23
error 1
error 4
```

Comment: thanks glenn!! i'm new to bash so...
and by the way when you declare "seen[100]=yes", does that work like in C meaning you will have a lot of possibly unnecessary memory (declaring an array of size 101) or it just uses one spot ?

Comment: I don't know. If you're concerned about a few kilobytes, and if your bash is version 4, use an associative array instead of a regular array. Change `local seen` to `local -A seen` -- your code will now also work with non-numeric input